# What is the name of this data strcucture, and where is used?

Tags: data-structures, tree

This data structure is for store words, where each letter is a node of a tree like this.

```
H -> E -> L -> O(f)
            -> L(f)
  -> I -> G -> H(f)
       -> L -> L(f)
```

So the root node is H and this has 2 childs, and the (f) indicate that is the end of the word.

Is this a know Data structure, have a name, and have know applications?

Because I want to use it, to save memory in a web scraper, but I read more about these pros and cons if this exists?

Comment: It's called TRIE

Comment: You can check this article on trie https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/advanced-data-structures/trie-keyword-tree/tutorial/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This data structure is called TRIE structure which are based on prefix of a string. These are mainly used to visualise strings as a graph
This will help you out
https://medium.com/basecs/trying-to-understand-tries-3ec6bede0014

Comment: Not TIRE. it's TRIE